# MongoDB server version error with $strLenCP operator, finding alternative to find the length of string

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using MongoDB version 2.6 as server. If I use `$strLenCP` operator to find the length of sting in my query it is throwing below error by mongoose.

```
name: 'MongoError',
message: 'invalid operator \'$strLenCP\'',
ok: 0,
errmsg: 'invalid operator \'$strLenCP\'',
code: 15999
```

Can anyone suggest me which operator I should use instead of `$strLenCP`, to find the length of the string. So that I can sort the output from aggregation pipeline using `$sort`.

Comment: There is no aggregation expression operator to get the length of string - in MongoDB v2.6 (see the MongoDB Manual v2.6 [Aggregation String Operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.6/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#string-expressions)).

Comment: yes, seen the docs. . The only way is to get the result and sort them using lodash, but it's time consuming. Is there any other way available?

Comment: Mongo 2.6 has been EOL for nearly 5 years...

Answer (score 0):

`$strLenCP` is New in version `3.4`